# Remove object from List

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

My List is

```
public List<BaseHomePage.QueueListItem> QueueDataSource
   {
    get { return this._queueDataSource; }
    set { this._queueDataSource = value; }
   }
```

and I want to remove the object from the list,my code is

```
for (int i = 0; i < _queueDataSource.Count; i++)
{
    object queue = _queueDataSource[i];

    if (objQuery.BranchOutQueue)
    {
        this._queueDataSource.Remove(queue);   //Here I want to getting error
    }
}
```

> Error : The best overload method match for
>   system.collections.Generic.List.Remove(BaseHome.QueueList)
>   has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `object` use [var](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

```
var queue = _queueDataSource[i];
```

Or to be specific you can use:

```
BaseHomePage.QueueListItem queue = _queueDataSource[i];
```

The reason you are getting the error is that `Remove` expects parameter of the same type as of List, since you are getting the object retruned in type `object` its not compatible.

Comment: +1 which we want to prefer. base on the `index` or base of the `object`? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `RemoveAt` instead base from the `object`

```
     for (int i = 0; i < _queueDataSource.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IsSuccess)
             _queueDataSource.RemoveAt(i)
        }
```